# Installing applications via USB

Tags: 14.04, usb, windows

My desktop does not have any kind of internet connection and I am trying to install applications to it such as Wine and VLC. I would like to install them via USB. I have another computer that has internet access but is windows based. IF you need any other information please let me know.

Comment: Duplicate of  http://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-or-packages-without-internet-offline

Answer (score 0):

Maybe download source tar.gz on usb & compile, but this is not user freindly, if you want to remove them, or download already build .deb & use dpkg -i, but this is not the most secure way to do, depending from where you grab them. Prefer to download tar.gz & build you own .deb instead.

I wonder why you dont have internet on desktop ?
pci, pcie or usb wifi or cable network adaptaters arent so much expensive today.